# solc and solc-select throwing traceback errors

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, decentralized-applications

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.9/bin/solc-select", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(solc_select())
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/solc_select/__main__.py", line 61, in solc_select
    switch_global_version(args.get(USE_VERSION), args.get("always_install"))
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/solc_select/solc_select.py", line 181, in switch_global_version
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"'{version}' must be installed prior to use.")
argparse.ArgumentTypeError: '0.8.9' must be installed prior to use.
```

traceback error with solc --version and solc-select use 0.8.9 commands

I have run npm install -g solc, error is persisting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
solc-select install version
solc-select use version
```

compiler needs to be installed first